# Detecting and modifying ListBox entries that contain digits

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

My program has about 25 entries, most of them string only. However, some of them are supposed to have digits in them, and I don't need those digits in the output (output should be string only). So, how can I "filter out" integers from strings?

Also, if I have integers, strings AND chars, how could I do it (for example, one `ListBox` entry is `E#2`, and should be renamed to `E#` and then printed as output)?

Comment: what do you mean by a list of both integer and string ? it's not possible...clarify the word `strings`

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post the code you're using now to get the user input and add it to your list and some examples of entries and expected results. We'll be able to show specifically what you need to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your entries are in a `List<string>`, you can loop through the list and then through each character of each entry, then check if it is a number and remove it. Something like this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>{ "abc123", "xxx111", "yyy222" };
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
    var no_numbers = "";
    foreach (char c in list[i]) {
        if (!Char.IsDigit(c))
            no_numbers += c;
    }
    list[i] = no_numbers;
}
```

This only removes digits as it seems you wanted from your question. If you want to remove all other characters except letters, you can change the logic a bit and use `Char.IsLetter()` instead of `Char.IsDigit()`.

Comment: This method was easiest for me to manipulate to get my supposed solution.

If only you could help me make a connection between List<string> and my listbox I'm supposed to use (i succeeded in working around it, but i think its unnecessary complication).

Thanks alot.

Comment: You bind your `ListBox` to the `List<string> list`. The way you do that depends on whether you're using WinForms or WPF. Add the code about binding to your question and add the WinForms or WPF tag so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all numbers from a strings with this LINQ solution:

```
string numbers = "Ho5w ar7e y9ou3?";

string noNumbers = new string(numbers.Where(c => !char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
```

**noNumbers** = `"How are you?"`

But you can also remove all numbers from a string by using a foreach loop :

```
string numbers = "Ho5w ar7e y9ou3?";

List<char> noNumList = new List<char>();

foreach (var c in numbers)
{
    if (!char.IsDigit(c))
        noNumList.Add(c);            
}

string noNumbers = string.Join("", noNumList);
```

If you want to remove all numbers from strings inside a collection :

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>() { 
"Ho5w ar7e y9ou3?", 
"W9he7re a3re y4ou go6ing?",
"He2ll4o!" 
};

List<char> noNumList = new List<char>();

for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (var c in myList[i])
    {
        if(!char.IsDigit(c))
            noNumList.Add(c);
    }
    myList[i] = string.Join("", noNumList);
    noNumList.Clear();
}
```

**myList** Output :

```
"How are you?"
"Where are you going?"
"Hello!"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what is your scenario, but given a string, you can loop through its characters, and if it's a number, discard it from output.

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
string entry = "E#2";
char[] output = new char[entry.Length];

for(int i = 0, j =0; i < entry.Length ; i++)
{
    if(!Char.IsDigit(entry[i]))
    {
        output[j] = entry[i];
        j++;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

I've tried to give you a simple solution with one loop and two index variables, avoiding string concatenations that can make performance lacks.

See this example working at [C# Online Compiler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K66IvS)

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong,maybe this is how your list looks ?

```
ABCD123
EFGH456
```

And your expected output is :

```
ABCD
EFGH
```

Is that correct?If so,assuming that it's a `List<string>`,then you can use the below code :

```
  list<string> mylist = new list<string>;

  foreach(string item in mylist)
   {

    ///To get letters/alphabets
    var letters = new String(item.Where(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());

    ///to get special characters

    var letters = new String(item.Where(Char.IsSymbol).ToArray())
   }
```

Now you can easily combine the codes :)

Comment: The OP claims to be learning c#, so I wouldn't suggest a LINQ solution. They most likely don't even know what LINQ is

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto,if not used LINQ, i hope u can guess how big the answer would be?(don't tell me u are suggesting regex) !

Comment: Well, LINQ is just a shortcut for foreach statements. Also, that foreach looks weird

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, how can u say a simple for loop would be enough ? after all the code should figure out which is alphabet and which is not right ?

Comment: Notice though that this wouldn't work for the OP's example though, as `E#` would print `E` (since `#` is not a letter but a symbol)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, i am editing the answer but i am waiting for the OP's response to check if this is what he's asking for

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, take a look at the answer again :)

Comment: That's rather worse than better, because you are separating the results and looping the string twice. You'd have to use either `!char.IsNumber` or `char.IsLetter || char.IsSymbol` for this to be correct

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto , noooo!!! I just gave two lines of code which can be combined as one or can be used separately...i am sure the OP can understand that .....

Comment: @zackraiyan I'm pretty sure i understand second portion of the code, except a first line. I can't really find a way to make a listBox into a "mylist" list to use the foreach function (i must use listboxes).
Thanks for the input tho.

Comment: @FedkaMladenovic,  do u mean u have a listbox instead of a list<string>?

Comment: @zackraiyan yes, exactly

Comment: @FedjaMladenovic,  just change the loop as follows : `foreach(var item in ListBox1.items)`

Comment: @zackraiyan Thanks alot... I guess it was a dumb question after all. I tried with `foreach(var item in listBox1)` and it of course didn't work... I'm still stumbling around in c#

Comment: @zackraiyan _foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'_ it displays the error on this line `foreach(var item in ListBox1.items)`

Comment: change `var` to `string` @FedjaMladenovic

Comment: @FedjaMladenovic, please make sure to mark the answer as answer :)